# Prolog: Force variables to initialise for command line printing

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a bash command which will open Prolog (or logtalk in this case), evaluate a variable (*A* here), write out the name of the variable and quit. I've come this far:

```
swilgt -q -s prolog/condep.lgt -s /tmp/tmp_xc5gfpp.lgt -g 'state::objectOfEvent(A,eve140642825991448), writeln(A).' -t halt.
```

however it outputs answers like `_9956`. However if I go forward into interactive mode and run the same query, it will output the correct answer.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742574/1525648) indicates that this is because the variable *A* is not yet initialised- how can I for *A* to initialise before writing out the answer?

Comment: Clearly, you are expecting for `state::objectOfEvent(A, eve140642825991448)` to cause A to become assigned, but it isn't. The reason why is certainly buried somewhere in the code for `state::objectOfEvent` but you haven't shown us that code. Ultimately, Prolog is saying it does not have a binding for A, and it's your problem to come up with that binding--if we say `A=foo`, that will cause A to "initialize" but is certainly not what you're asking really.

Comment: @DanielLyons I didn't explain it very well at all but if I continue to interactive mode I CAN get an answer for A. I've edited the question to hopefully make a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in interactive mode and it was printing the first possible answer (_9956, the variable placeholder), BEFORE evaluaing *A* according to `state::objectOfEvent`, then printing the 'true' answer to *A*.

I could eliminate the placeholder option by ensuring the value of A was [not a free variable using nonvar/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=typetest):

```
state::objectOfEvent(A,eve140642825991448), nonvar(A), write(A)
```

This feels pretty hacky and I'd love to hear any better solutions.

Comment: Correct your code so that `state::objectOfEvent` does not produce "solutions" that fail to unify anything with an uninstantiated first argument?